# iOS API for detecting keyboard press/releases

Tags: ios, keyboard

So the UITextField can take keyboard input, but is there any way to detect when a particular button on the keyboard (in particular external keyboards) is pressed/released?

If not, is it possible to hook directly to bluetooth keyboards for iPad/iPhone and get their signals directly?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a UITextField for user input and implement its delegate methods in order to control what the user is typing. You can implement

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

which is called every time the user enters a character in the text field, and check the character entered in there.

Comment: Hmm, I suppose that would work for presses, but what about for detecting releases? i.e I don't think this would work for implementing, say, WSAD controls for quake

Comment: So i take it that you're not looking for text input?

Comment: No, not really. I want to be able to detect shift key presses, in particular for when using physical keyboards, but I guess this is the best that iOS has to offer..